# Rationalize a denominator with 3 nth roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, rationalising-denominator

How would you rationalize a denomiator with $3$ or more arbitary roots, like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}+\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[7]{3}}$? I knew an absolutely awful formula for $3$ cube roots, but aside from that I could only find special cases. Does there exist a general formula? If so, what is it? (I know this question is pointless, but still.)

Apparently it's really difficult to do this by hand for arbitrary radicals. I posted this a long time ago, and since then, I've found a few new formulas through experimentation. $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}=\frac{\left(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{c}\right)\left(2\sqrt{bc}+a-b-c\right)}{\left(a-b-c\right)^{2}-4bc}$$ $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}+\sqrt[3]{c}}=\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{a^{2}}+\sqrt[3]{b^{2}}+\sqrt[3]{c^{2}}-\sqrt[3]{ab}-\sqrt[3]{ac}-\sqrt[3]{bc}\right)\left(\left(3\sqrt[3]{abc}+a+b+c\right)^{2}-3\left(a+b+c\right)\sqrt[3]{abc}\right)}{\left(a+b+c\right)^{3}-27abc}$$ $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{a}+\sqrt[4]{b}+\sqrt[4]{c}}=\frac{\left(\sqrt[4]{a}+\sqrt[4]{b}-\sqrt[4]{c}\right)\left(\sqrt[4]{a}-\sqrt[4]{b}+\sqrt[4]{c}\right)\left(\sqrt[4]{a}-\sqrt[4]{b}-\sqrt[4]{c}\right)\left(2\sqrt{bc}-2\sqrt{ab}-2\sqrt{ac}-a-b-c\right)\left(\left(12a+4b+4c\right)\sqrt{bc}+\left(a-b-c\right)^{2}+4bc\right)}{\left(12a+4b+4c\right)^{2}bc-\left(\left(a-b-c\right)^{2}+4bc\right)^{2}}$$ $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[5]{a}+\sqrt[5]{b}+\sqrt[5]{c}}=\frac{2abc\left(\left(\sqrt[5]{a^{2}}+\sqrt[5]{b^{2}}\right)\sqrt[5]{ab}+\left(\sqrt[5]{a^{2}}+\sqrt[5]{c^{2}}\right)\sqrt[5]{ac}+\left(\sqrt[5]{b^{2}}+\sqrt[5]{c^{2}}\right)\sqrt[5]{bc}-\sqrt[5]{a^{4}}-\sqrt[5]{b^{4}}-\sqrt[5]{c^{4}}-\sqrt[5]{a^{2}b^{2}}-\sqrt[5]{a^{2}c^{2}}-\sqrt[5]{b^{2}c^{2}}-\left(2\sqrt[5]{a}+2\sqrt[5]{b}-3\sqrt[5]{c}\right)\sqrt[5]{abc}\right)\left(\left(\sqrt{4a^{2}b^{2}c^{2}v^{3}+1}-1\right)q_{1}\left(\frac{1}{a^{2}b^{2}c}\right)+2abcq_{2}\left(\frac{1}{a^{2}b^{2}c}\right)\right)p\left(\frac{\sqrt[5]{a^{3}b^{3}c^{4}}}{abc}\right)}{\left(q_{1}\left(\frac{1}{a^{2}b^{2}c}\right)-2abcq_{2}\left(\frac{1}{a^{2}b^{2}c}\right)\right)^{2}-\left(4a^{2}b^{2}c^{2}v^{3}+1\right)q_{1}\left(\frac{1}{a^{2}b^{2}c}\right)^{2}}$$ $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{a}+\sqrt[6]{b}+\sqrt[6]{c}}=\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}+\sqrt[3]{c}-\sqrt[6]{ab}-\sqrt[6]{ac}-\sqrt[6]{bc}\right)\left(\left(3\sqrt[6]{abc}+\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)^{2}-3\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)\sqrt[6]{abc}\right)\left(\left(a+3b+3c\right)\sqrt{a}+\left(3a+b+3c\right)\sqrt{b}-\left(3a+3b+c\right)\sqrt{c}+21\sqrt{abc}\right)\left(2\left(a+3b+3c\right)\left(3a+b+3c\right)\sqrt{ab}+42\left(3a+3b+c\right)\sqrt{abc^{2}}-a\left(a+3b+3c\right)^{2}-b\left(3a+b+3c\right)^{2}+c\left(3a+3b+c\right)^{2}+441abc\right)}{4ab\left(21c\left(3a+3b+c\right)+\left(a+3b+3c\right)\left(3a+b+3c\right)\right)^{2}-\left(a\left(a+3b+3c\right)^{2}+b\left(3a+b+3c\right)^{2}-c\left(3a+3b+c\right)^{2}-441abc\right)^{2}}$$ Where $$p\left(x\right)=\frac{xq\left(x^{5}\right)}{5abcx^{3}-\left(a+b+c\right)x-5}$$ $$q\left(x\right)=u^{5}x^{3}+3Au^{4}x^{2}+3u^{2}\left(A^{2}u+BC\right)x+\left(A^{3}u^{2}-C^{3}u+B^{3}+3ABCu\right)=q_{1}\left(x\right)u+q_{2}\left(x\right)$$ $$A=\left(5v^{4}-5u^{2}v\right)$$ $$B=\left(10u^{2}v^{2}-v^{5}\right)$$ $$C=\left(10uv^{3}-u^{3}\right)$$ $$u=-\frac{\sqrt{4a^{2}b^{2}c^{2}v^{3}+1}+1}{2abc}$$ $$v=-\frac{a+b+c}{15abc}$$ and $q_1(x)$ and $q_2(x)$ have rational coefficients. As for the general case, it seems to involve a matrix inversion. I don't know linear algebra yet, so this wasn't very clear to me. I'm not anywhere near the age I'd need to be to learn it in school, and in fact, most of my peers don't even know how to rationalize $\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}}$. I really don't feel like waiting for the curriculum to get there, so I have $2$ more questions. Is there a way to do the arbitrary case using only elementary algebra, and where would be a good resource to learn linear algebra in order to do this?

UPDATE: In order to do this in general, use complex numbers so that $n$th roots have $n$ branches. Then take the product over all combinations of the branches. In the example problem, this leads to $2\cdot3\cdot7=42$ possible factors, $1$ of which is the original denominator. For $3$ $n$th roots, the product $$N=\prod_{u,\ v,\ w}^{\ }\left(\sqrt[n]{a_{u}}+\sqrt[n]{b_{v}}+\sqrt[n]{c_{w}}\right)$$ is an integer, where subscripts are used to distinguish branches so it's easier to see what's happening here. In complex exponential form, you have $$N=\prod_{u,\ v,\ w}^{\ }\left(e^{\frac{2\pi ui}{n}}\sqrt[n]{a}+e^{\frac{2\pi vi}{n}}\sqrt[n]{b}+e^{\frac{2\pi wi}{n}}\sqrt[n]{c}\right)$$ This answer was given by Christophe Leuridan.

Comment: not sure what you did. All you need is $(a+b+c)(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 -bc-ca-ab )= a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc$

Comment: That expression can be expressed as the root of a 42nd-degree polynomial, too long to write out here.

Comment: @Will Jagy wow that's much simpler... My thought process was this. First, I found a cubic that has ∛u+∛v+W as a solution, then set W=∛w. Then I reversed the order of the coefficients, which reciprocates the solution, and solved this new cubic with the cubic formula. Then I finished it off with the difference of cubes identity.

Comment: @Dan what is the process of finding that polynomial, how would it generalize, and how would you solve the "reverse order" polynomial to rationalize it? (see my other comment)

Comment: Linear algebra. Represent an element of $\Bbb Q[\sqrt5,\sqrt[3]2,\sqrt[7]3]$ as a $2\times3\times7=42$-dimensional vector, represent multiplication by $\sqrt5+\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt[7]3$ as a $42\times42$ matrix $M$, and find the vector satisfying $Mv=(1,0,\dots,0)^\top$ using Gaussian elimination.

Comment: A simple application of the formula Will Jagy gave will still leave you with a single cube root in the denominator (the $3abc = 3\sqrt[3]{uvw}$ term). But just one radical in the denominator is much easier to rationalize in a second step. As the other comments suggest, the general process of rationalizing denominators is not for the faint of heart. Are you sure that doing so would be worth the effort?

Comment: [See Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F%285%5E%281%2F2%29%2B2%5E%281%2F3%29%2B3%5E%281%2F7%29%29).  The radical expression is pretty messy.  You may prefer to leave the denominator unrationalized, or use the numerical approximation (0.21432001282883892).

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes because I'm doing this as its own problem, not part of a larger problem for any kind of practical applications. :)

Comment: Perfectly fine. then Akiva Weinberger has given you an approach, though the description makes it sound scarier than it is. The 42 dimensions are spanned by the basis $\{\sqrt 5^k\sqrt[3]2^m\sqrt[7]3^n \mid 0\le k \le 1, 0\le m\le 2, 0 \le n \le 6\}$, and the Matrix $M$ is mostly $0$s with only three $1$s per row (or column - I haven't worked out which is which). It's still bad, but it could be done by hand in a not unreasonable amount of time.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks! Yeah I was worried about that but it's definitely doable. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a specialist of algebra, but I beleieve that the product
$$\prod_{k,\ell,m}\big((-1)^k\sqrt{5}+e^{i\ell2\pi/3}\sqrt[3]{2}+e^{i\ell2\pi/7}\sqrt[7]{3}\big)$$
over all integers $k \in [0,1]$, $\ell \in [0,2]$, $m \in [0,6]$ is an integer, called the norm of the algebraic integer $\sqrt{5}+\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[7]{3}$. This gives a formula for the inverse. See also
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_norm and
[Norm and Algebraic Integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3197034/norm-and-algebraic-integers)

Comment: That seems like a really helpful concept! However, it doesn't seem any simpler than the method described by Akiva Weinberger. Is there an easier way of interpreting this, or is it known to be a fundamentally high tech procedure? If there isn't a simpler understanding then this is definitely the best answer.

Comment: It is related to the method described by Akiva Weinberger. The norm is also the determinant of the linear map he considered, and the factors in the product above are the eigenvalues.

Comment: Ok, I'm an idiot. I finally set aside the advanced notation used in the linked articles, and it's actually really simple what's happening here. In fact, it's a straight forward generalization of a method I already came up with for rationalizing square roots. Noticed the $1$st few factors in the $4$th root formula? It's so annoying that I was staring the answer in the face all that time, especially since I spent hours trying to figure out those damn $5$th roots.